# How to pass an image with feed_dict in Tensorflow session run

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision

I need to pass an image during session Run in Tensorflow

I have tried

```
myimage="andrew/semaphore.jpg"
mydict={'ssignals':myimage}
output = sess.run(train_prediction, feed_dict=mydict)
```

but doesn't work

Returns me the error:

```
Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor
```

`train_prediction` tensor has the `shape=(3, 120), dtype=float32`
(120 is the number of training classes in which images are grouped)

the program load and labels input images with this method

```
def write_records_file(dataset, record_location):
    writer = None
    global counter
    global start_time

    current_index = 0
    for breed, images_filenames in dataset.items():
        for image_filename in images_filenames:
            with tf.Graph().as_default():
                with tf.Session() as sess:
                    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
                    if current_index % 100 == 0:
                        if writer:
                            writer.close()

                        record_filename = "{record_location}-{current_index}.tfrecords".format(
                            record_location=record_location,
                            current_index=current_index)
                        writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(record_filename)
                    current_index += 1

                    image_file = tf.read_file(image_filename)
                    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_file)

                    grayscale_image = tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(image)
                    resized_image = tf.image.resize_images(
                        grayscale_image, [250, 251])
                    try:
                        image_bytes = sess.run(
                            tf.cast(resized_image, tf.uint8)).tobytes()
                    except:
                        continue

                    image_label = breed.encode("utf-8")
                    example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
                        'label': tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[image_label])),
                        'image': tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[image_bytes]))
                    }))
                    writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
                    counter += 1
```

than a batch load the record and feed the CNN

EDIT

**I don't use same symbol-key value please before flag as duplicate pay attention.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tensorflow 'feed\_dict': using same symbol for key-value pair got 'TypeError: Cannot interpret feed\_dict key as Tensor'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37267584/tensorflow-feed-dict-using-same-symbol-for-key-value-pair-got-typeerror-can)

Comment: @running.t It's a totally different question, I don't use same symbol key-value

Comment: Where does the string `'ssignals'` come from? Typically the key in a `feed_dict` is a `tf.Tensor` object (such as a `tf.placeholder()`).

Comment: @mrry It's a simple string. So I cannot use string as label for feed dict. In this case what should I put as dictionary key that have as value a single picture `myimage`?

Comment: You can only use a string as a feed dict key if it's the name of a particular `tf.Tensor`, but generally it's easier to use the `tf.Tensor` object itself as the key. The correct `tf.Tensor` to pass will depend on the rest of your program: can you share more of the code?

Comment: @mrry The above code is almost the same of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41618096/how-to-use-a-trained-cnn-model-for-object-identification-in-tensorflow
I have the trained model and I'm tying to determine the best matching

Comment: Unfortunately, that question doesn't seem to have enough information. Presumably `train_prediction` depends on some input tensor, but it doesn't seem to be defined.

Comment: @mrry `train_prediction` tensor has the `shape=(3, 120), dtype=float32`
(120 is the number of training classes in which images are grouped)

Comment: What is the name of the input tensor in your network?

Comment: @mrry the first input that goes in the first convolution level is `float_image_batch`

Comment: Is it computed from the `tf.decode_jpeg()` tensor? If so, what's the name of the input to `tf.decode_jpeg()`?

Comment: @mrry the input of `tf.decode_jpeg()` is named `image_file` all these images are labeled and stored as TFR record and than is created a batch that feed the CNN

Comment: You could try `sess.run(train_prediction, feed_dict={image_file: myimage})`. It's hard to say if it'll work without seeing the intermediate code.

Comment: @mrry in this way doesn't work I get the error `name 'image_file  is not defined` seems isn't able to see `image_file` variable

Comment: Without seeing your program, I can't tell what the fix is. Presumably `image_file` is defined in a different scope from your `sess.run()` call. You'll need to restructure the code to make it visible.

Comment: @mrry I have added the whole method used to write the TFR record used in the batch that feeds the CNN. (note that this method isn't invoked all the code is in the same file )

Comment: From that example, it looks like your prediction program (which defines `train_prediction`) is a completely separate program from the one that decodes JPEG images. I'm guessing that you'll have a tensor in your program that gets image data as bytes from a `tf.Example` proto. You can either parse the JPEG in Python and feed in the parsed data to that tensor, or restructure your training program to handle input from a file as well.